# Using Solr with Jasper Reports

Tags: java, solr, jasper-reports, integration, jasperserver

I'm working on a spike(research project) and I need to find out if we can use jasper reports "COMMUNITY VERSION" with Solr at all. I found this suggestion of using custom datasource: https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/705431/it-possible-use-solr

The real question is, has anyone tried this in practice? I installed the server and I'm not seeing any sign of that in the community version.

If the answer is yes, please be specific whether it's community version or not. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Since then, it looks like a JDBC driver was released: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_2/parallel-sql-interface.html#jdbc-driver

Community version or not, JDBC is the easiest way for JasperReports (library or server) to connect to a data source. I have not tried it but I see no reason why it shouldn't work.

Another option is the [Web Service Data Source](https://community.jaspersoft.com/project/web-service-data-source), which you could use with the *HTTP Interface* of Solr.